# Get Client Date format

Tags: c#, javascript

I am getting a date from ActiveX component (developed in .NET.  The date format is not known i.e give like ***DateTime.Now.toString()*** ). so i am getting date **June 8th, 2012** instead of **Aug 18th, 2012.**. How can i get Aug 18th, 2012 when use `new Date()`?

Here is the code:

```
signerDetails = signerLib.FetchCertDetails();
var certDetails = signerDetails.split('$$$$$$');
var cardDate = new Date(certDetails[1])
```

Comment: are you developing a Client/Server App?

Comment: What is the value of `certDetails[1]` that gives 8 June, 2012?

Comment: Are those really the dates in question? I can understand how you might get Aug 6th if it was written as 8/6/2012 which could be interpreted as month/day/year or day/month/year but coming out with aug 18th just seems very strange since it would seem any date string representing that would be unambiguous...

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you update your ActiveX component to return the date in RFC2822 or ISO 8601 format, that way you can create a new instance of the date without any sort of manual parsing. Pretty simple to do that in C#, .NET has a built in [format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#Roundtrip) e.g.

```
var iso8601Date = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o");
```

There is an overload of the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) class which takes in the date as string, this internally calls [Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) which expects the date in that particular format.

Alternatively, you could have your date returned in [epoch format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) however that would require some extra work.